# Functions that modify map keys

Tags: dafny

I'm having trouble verifying a function that modifies the keys of a map.

```
function ConvertMap(inputs: map<nat, bool>, f: nat->nat): map<nat, bool>
    ensures ConvertMap(inputs, f) == (map k | k in inputs :: f(k) := inputs[k])
{
    map k | k in inputs :: f(k) := inputs[k]
                           ^^^^
}
```

where the error seen is "key expressions might be referring to the same value".

I can resolve this by adding a constraint on the function `f`:

```
function ConvertMap(inputs: map<nat, bool>, f: nat->nat): map<nat, bool>
    requires forall n1: nat, n2: nat :: n1 != n2 ==> f(n1) != f(n2)
    ensures ConvertMap(inputs, f) == (map k | k in inputs :: f(k) := inputs[k])
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    map k | k in inputs :: f(k) := inputs[k]
}
```

However, then I see the error "This postcondition might not hold on a return path."

I'm unsure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did manage to make this verify with a universal quantifier rather than an equality:

```dafny
function ConvertMap(inputs: map<nat, bool>, f: nat->nat): (r:map<nat, bool>)
requires forall n1: nat, n2: nat :: n1 != n2 ==> f(n1) != f(n2)
ensures forall k :: k in inputs <==> f(k) in r
ensures forall k :: k in inputs ==> r[f(k)] == inputs[k]
{
    map k | k in inputs :: f(k) := inputs[k]
}
```

My thinking here was simplify that Dafny might struggle to show the equality of two maps in this way.  So breaking it up might help ... which it did.

Comment: I don't think this is proving something as strong, since it doesn't check that there aren't additional elements in `r` that don't correspond to an element from `inputs`.

Comment: You can replace `==>` with `<==>` in first postcondition

Comment: Thanks Divyanshu!  I updated the solution.